# image dataset uploading in google colab

Tags: dataset, image-classification

I want to use a dataset in colab for training CNN. How to upload a dataset of gestures of 26 labels where each label has over 2400 images. Total size of data is around 1.5 GB but there are too many individual images and uploading it in drive hangs the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Zip them! Less space, easier uploading, unpack is quite fast (you can do it in additional initialization procedure and to comment it out after first session initialization)